# Add properties to class dynamically C#

Tags: c#

I want to add properties to a class dynamically and set values to them. Could someone point me in the right direction to some tutorials or articles or even better provide an example.

I have a base class which is called in a foreach loop. Inside this class I need to add up to 30 properties and set values to them.

This is the method that calls the class.

```
foreach (Class name in this.list)
{
    ClassBeingCalled class = new ClassBeingCalled (name);
    class.Populate();
    this.newlist.Add(class);
}
```

Now inside the class being called, I need to create the 30 or so properties on the fly, which will be set in the "Populate" method of that class.

Like so...

```
 foreach (PropertyToAssign count2 in listofproperties)
 {
     string name = "_nameofproperty" + count2.name
     base.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                          BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(this, count2);
 }
```

Comment: Whats wrong with just using 'listofproperties' rather than trying to create dynamic properties?  If it must be Dynamic have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx

Comment: Do those things *exist* as properties? i.e. are you trying to create *new* properties? or assign values to the existing properties?

Comment: Trying to create new properties. Currently, it has a set number of properties which I would like to change to dynamic. So for example, it has 10 properties. However if a new property is added to listofproperties, it errors here:

    base.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                          BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(this, count2);

as there are more properties than are defined.

Comment: I think you should possibly consider just using an internal dictionary with an indexer, so you would access your properties like `myObject["PropertyName"]` (you can achieve effectively the same thing with an [ExpandObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)).

Comment: Btw, in title it says "Property" but in populate method it reflects "Fields"

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to approach this.

a) You use reflection to generate a class at runtime with whatever you need. You can always derive this generated class from a base class that contains `Populate` but I don't see the need.

b) If you're using C# 4.0+, you could use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), which allows you to set whatever properties you want for your needs. Note that these are *not* added as properties per se, as it uses the DLR which is all runtime-based. Depending on your needs, this may be fine; this is pretty much the same as approach c, but using the DLR.

c) You could use a backing dictionary and use an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), like so:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> _internalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

public T this[string propName]
{
    get {
        return _internalData[propName];
    }
    set {
        _internalData[propName] = value;
    }
}
```

By using approach 3, you're actually indexing based on `string`s which is probably better based on your requirements... As you can do something along the lines of this:

```
foreach (PropertyToAssign count2 in listofproperties)
{
    string name = "_nameofproperty" + count2.name;
    this[name] = count2.value;
}
```

---

At the end of the day, it's probably best if you explain the problem you're trying to solve, as there may be a better way to approach it entirely.

Comment: I thought I did above :-(. What other info do you need?

Comment: You suggested your already-existing solution of setting properties on a class and told us that you need to add properties. In reality you should probably look into option c here (also been suggested by others in this question) and instead of setting the property, just set the value on the internal dictionary.

Comment: How would I define the type of property in the dictionary?

Comment: Well, you don't. You use `object` so that you can stick anything in there. If you only have 1 datatype you can always change `object` to `string`, or whatever that type is.

Comment: Hi Rudi,

I get the following error:

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'BusinessLogic.InvoiceBaseUIBindable'

After I added this - this[name] = count2.value;

Comment: Well, did you add the dictionary and the indexer code on `InvoiceBaseUIBindable`?

Comment: I couldn't add the indexer code. It gave me the "are you missing an assembly etc" message....

Comment: `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add dynamic properties to a compiled class on the fly. You can only add dynamic properties to classes while building the class itself on the fly using [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx)

Your other option could be using a Dictionary or [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) (which is actually a dictionary). But for this option, you cannot access your dynamic properties using reflection.